# Ajax запрос и его прерыввание

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Есть скрипт:

```
function search_handler(form) {
$('#bodycatalog').html("<span class='load'></span>");
    var number = 10; //количество постов
    var offset = 0; //смещение постов
    var busy = false;
    if (!busy){
    busy = true;
    $.get("/wp-content/themes/theme/handler/handler.php", { 
    off: offset,
    angle: form.angle.value,
    protect: form.protectlvl.value,
    color: form.colorz.value,
    volt: form.volt.value,
    power: form.power.value,
    byuse: form.byuse.value
    },
    function(data){
        if(data == ""){
            if($(".notfound").length==0) {
                $('#bodycatalog').append("<tr><td><span class='notfound'>Извините, но по вашему запросу ничего не найдено. Попробуйте изменить параметры фильтрации.</span></td></tr>");
            }
            $('.load').remove();
        }
        else{
            $('#bodycatalog').html(data);
            offset = offset+number;
            busy = false;
            $(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {
                if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 1200 && !busy) {
                busy = true;
                    $("#catalog").after("<span class='load'></span>");
                $.get("/wp-content/themes/theme/handler/handler.php", { 
                off: offset,
                angle: form.angle.value,
                protect: form.protectlvl.value,
                color: form.colorz.value,
                volt: form.volt.value,
                power: form.power.value,
                byuse: form.byuse.value
                },
                function(data){
                    if(data == ""){
                        $('.load').remove();
                    }
                    else{
                        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 600){
                        $('#bodycatalog').append(data);
                        $('.load').remove();
                        offset = offset+number;
                        }
                        busy = false;
                    }
                });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

Обработчик handler.php выдает из бд фильтрованные посты.
И подгружает их при скролле по 10 шт...

Проблема: При резкой смене параметров фильтра, предыдущий запрос к бд продолжает работать. И они вместе с новым совмещаются, выдавая не правильный результат.

Задача: При смене параметров фильтра прерывать предыдущий запрос..

Comment: синхронный запрос не решает вашу проблему?

Comment: установите флаг типа loaded и смотрите, если флаг === false, тогда не вызывайте обработчик события (это делается в самом обработчике), ну и в true выставляете его только тогда, когда предыдущий ajax запрос полностью отработал

Comment: А при нем будет работать добавление постов при скроле?

Comment: @FLK - то, что вы написали это **худшее** что можно было посоветовать

Comment: у меня была похожая задача, сказали прервать не получится.

Comment: @AlexWindHope пробывал играться с флагами.. но как они мне помогут не понимаю..
Вы говорите, когда предыдущий ajax запрос, а как это определить?

Comment: хотя нет, не так.. 
у меня выходит, что предыдущий ajax запрос полностью отработал, только тогда, когда человек проскролил все посты.. а ведь он может взглянуть на парочку и поменять фильтр..

Comment: пытаюсь использовать такое
 if(xhr != null){
 xhr.abort();
 xhr2.abort();
 }
не помогает..

Comment: @alexxxer1234 - суть я описал, писать весь код за вас нет желания, возможно вам поможет [это](http://hashcode.ru/questions/68795/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0), задача здесь абсолютно иная, но здесь тоже применяется флаг и тоже речь о xhr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно блокировать ваши фильтры на время выполнения запроса.
[Смотрите примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/xRRRX/2/). Может и примитивно, но позволит избежать случаев, когда невминяемый юзверь лупит по фильтрам, как пулемет.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() { $(':checkbox').prop('disabled', true); },
    complete: function() { $(':checkbox').prop('disabled', false);}
});
$(":checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/echo/html/'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: хм, случайно пульнул на правильный ответ..
На самом деле я попытался по всякому поиграться с событиями, но не выходит.. 
Думаю всему виной второй вложенный запрос, который работает при скроле